# jQuery child selector expression

Tags: jquery, html, dom, css-selectors

```
<div id="div">
    <div> <!-- first level -->
        <div> <!-- second level -->
            <div>1.1</div> <!-- third level -->
            <div>1.2</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div></div>
            <div>2.2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What are the **jQuery selector expressions** for selecting the followings:
1. div commented by **first level**
2. divs commented by **second level**
3. divs commented by **third level**

Comment: Please do not use ">div" as selector, because the html dom tag is dynamic. It may be div, or may be ul or li etc.

Comment: Make sure to accept answers to your questions by clicking the checkmark beside the answer that helped you resolve the problem, makes your questions much more desirable to answerers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to all of these is either the `>` (child) selector or the [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)  method.

First level:

```
$("#div > div")...
$("#div").children("div")...
```

Second level:

```
$("#div > div > div")...
$("#div").children("div").children("div")...
```

Third level:

```
$("#div > div > div > div")...
$("#div").children("div").children("div").children("div")...
```

If you're not interested in a particular tag (eg div) then simply don't specify a selector to `children()`. For example, all second level elements:

```
$("#div").children().children()...
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the immediate child selector `>` in this case:

- First level:

  - `$("#div > div")`
  - `$("#div > *")` (generic version)
- Second level:

  - `$("#div > div > div")`
  - `$("#div > * > *")` (generic version)
- Third Level:

  - `$("#div > div > div > div")`
  - `$("#div > * > * > *")` (generic version)

The equivalent generic is `.children()` without a selector as well, e.g.:

```
$("#div").children()
$("#div").children().children()
$("#div").children().children().children()
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same as the CSS selectors for them.

Edited for your new requirements:

```
#div > *
#div > * > *
#div > * > * > *
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `$('#div > *')` - This will select all tags that are a direct decedent of the element `#div`. Without using the child selector `>`, you would get all tags within the element #div, not just the first level.
2. `$('#div > * > *')` - Same idea as #1
3. `$('#div > * > * > *')`

Answer (score 0):

they are true but for selecting specifically your first items, use this;

```
first level : $("#div").children("div:first-child")

Second level: $("#div:first-child").children("div:first-child").children("div:first-child")

Third level: $("#div").children("div":first-child).children("div:first-child").children("div:first-child")
```